# psycopg: can't copy from csv to postgresql with python, no results

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I have simple postgresql db with oid. The number of columns and their names are similar to the headers in the csv file. 
I'm trying to use copy command:

```
def db_copy_images(self, file):

    my_file = open(file)

    try:
        self.process_file('images_original', my_file)
    finally:
        pass

def process_file(self, table, csv_file):

    dbname = 'v'
    user = 'on'
    password = 'on'
    host = 'ip'
    port = 5432

    SQL_STATEMENT = """COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER AS '|' CSV HEADER"""

    print ("OK")
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=dbname,user=user,password=password,host=host,port=port)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    for line in csv_file:
        print(line)


    #cursor.copy_expert(sql = SQL_STATEMENT % table, file = csv_file)
    cursor.copy_expert("COPY images_original FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER AS '|' CSV HEADER", file = csv_file)
    cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
```

I got a list of lines as output and then my process becomes finished. But there are no changes in database, and no errors. How can I debug that? Here is my --trace:

```
manager_db.py(63):         cursor.copy_expert("COPY images_original FROM STDOUT WITH DELIMITER AS '|' CSV HEADER", file = csv_file)
manager_db.py(66):         cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
manager_db.py(68):         conn.commit
manager_db.py(69):         cursor.close
manager_db.py(70):         conn.close
manager_db.py(36):             pass
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)
```

here is my db create:

```
CREATE TABLE images_original
(
  "image id" integer NOT NULL,
  "file url" character varying NOT NULL,
  "file format id" integer,
  "file format" character varying,
  "file width" integer,
  "file height" integer,
  "file quality factor" integer,
  "file bit depth" integer,
  "file margin" integer,
  "file bg color" integer,
  "file size" integer,
  "scaling factor" character varying,
  delta character varying
)
WITH (
  OIDS=TRUE
);
ALTER TABLE images_original
  OWNER TO on;
```

and fist rows in my test file:

```
image id|file url|file format id|file format|file width|file height|file quality factor|file bit depth|file margin|file bg color|file size|scaling factor|delta
172317239|http://cps-static.r.com/2/Open/NBC/The%20Office/Steve%20Carell%204.jpg|0||2336|3504|||||949406||INS
172317239|http://cps-static.r.com/2/Open/NBC/The%20Office/_derived_jpg_q90_0x200_m0/Steve%20Carell%204.jpg|1391886|jpg|133|200|90|24|0|24|6624|5.69|INS
172317239|http://cps-static.r.com/2/Open/NBC/The%20Office/_derived_jpg_q90_155x235_m0/Steve%20Carell%204.jpg|1391887|jpg|155|232|90|24|0|24|8092|6.64|INS
```

Comment: `FROM STDOUT` is weird. Normally it's `FROM STDIN` or `TO STDOUT`. See the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: can you provide the first dozen or so lines from the images_original file and edit into your question?  Also, the sql to create the table you are copying in to would be handy to figure out why your copy in command doesn't work.

Comment: @Greg I added new data to the post.

Comment: @DanielVérité actually I tried both and forgot to edit - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for updating the question.  It is a bit unusual to have spaces in column names, not impossible though.  I tried entering your copy line directly from psql command line.  It worked.  Then it jumped out at me:

```
for line in csv_file:
    print(line)

csv_file.seek(0)
```

When you print the data from the file you move the file pointer.  seek(0) resets it to the beginning.  This command should work if you add the seek, or, simply eliminate the loop that prints the files contents.

-g

Comment: I tried to do this copy command without this loop, I added it only to check that my STDIN isn't empty. I changed my script to `cursor.execute("COPY..")`, that origionally requires superuser rights. It works, but with some limitation, that aren't so necessary for me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Interesting.  I ran your script above, just removing the self references.  It populated the table just like you had it.